# find variables are true with isset

Tags: php

sorry. my English is weak.
my code in php:

```
$code=isset($_GET['q1']) ||  isset($_GET['q2']);
var_dump($code);
```

My Question is: 
if `$code==true` and just one of cases is true,
how to find this case? `$_GET['q1']` or `$_GET['q2']`?

Comment: Formatting your post has nothing do with your grasp on the English language yet you are lacking in that. Please, take the [tour].

Comment: You are looking for the keyword [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['q1'])) {
} else if (isset($_GET['q2'])) {
}
```

You can use something like the above I believe, although there will be other easier ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an **if statement** - which is a type of **conditional statement**.

```
if (isset($_GET['q1']) && $_GET['q1'] !== '') {
    $code = $_GET['q1'];
} elseif (isset($_GET['q2']) && $_GET['q2'] !== '') {
    $code = $_GET['q2'];
}
```

the issue with this however is that in the case that `$_GET['q1']` and `$_GET['q2']` are both set, then `$code` will always be `q1` because it's the first reached true statement.

so unless you're 100% certain only one or t'other will be set, this is ok.

ref: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php